# minted code samples more "condensed" than lst-listing

Tags: listings, minted

I want to switch to minted over listings for the superior syntax highlighting, especially for C++.
But I can't get the font to look as nicely as with listings. Somehow the font is heavier and more condensed when generated with minted.

Here's an example (listings above, minted below):

[image: listings above, minted below]

This is my config for both of them:

```
\newfontfamily\UbuntuMono{Ubuntu Mono}
\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}

\lstset{
  backgroundcolor=\color{dsolar_back},
  basicstyle=\UbuntuMono\footnotesize\color{dsolar_text},
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  breaklines=true, 
  captionpos=b,
  commentstyle=\color{dsolar_comm},
  extendedchars=true, 
  frame=single, 
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\color{dsolar_keyw}, 
  language=[11]C++,              
  numbers=left,                
  numbersep=5pt,
  rulecolor=\color{lightgrey},
  showspaces=false, 
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  stepnumber=2,
  stringstyle=\color{dsolar_ltrl},
  tabsize=4,
  title=\lstname
}

\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}

\setminted[c++]{
    linenos=true,
    bgcolor=dsolar_back,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    style=solarizedlight,
    frame=single,
    framesep=0pt,
    rulecolor=\color{lightgrey},
    stepnumber=2,
    numbersep=5pt,
    resetmargins=true
}
```

Has anyone had experience with this? Are the some settings that I am missing? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the default behaviors. If you are using a monospace font, you should follow the `minted`'s spacing, because the wide spacing in `listings` is just to make sure that even normal fonts become monospace.

If you want to use a wide font, you can borrow `microtype`.

In the following code, the above is the normal spacing, the below is the modified spacing. I don't have your font family, so I use a similar one (DejaVu Sans Mono):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{DejaVuSansMono}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[letterspace=100]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{myminted}
{\VerbatimEnvironment
\begingroup\lsstyle
\begin{minted}{C++}}
{\end{minted}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{minted}{C++}
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!");
}
\end{minted}

\begin{myminted}
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!");
}
\end{myminted}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This fixes the spacing, thanks! Concerning the minted code being "heavier" / darker, this is apparently a problem with listings where the text color isn't the actual colour set via the options but a shade light for some reason. [I verified with a colour picker that the minted colour is correct.]

Comment: @h-2 If you use a normal font (not a `typewriter` font) in `listings`, you will know why `listings` produces such a giant space (I don't like it). Some people don't like formatting their code with code fonts :)

Comment: Is there a way to get `\lsstyle` into the minted options and not having to create a new env?

Comment: @h-2 I don't know yet. I don't use `minted` often recently so I don't think I am confident enough. But you can do some trial-and-error tests on `fontstyle`, etc. Anyway I think defining a new environment is the best option.